# Android Robolectric initialize the application twice

Tags: android, testing, robolectric

I'm testing my app with Robolectric, when I test each method by itself every thing goes right, but when I test a couples of methods together a RuntimeException is raised saying " ParsePlugins is already initialized", so obviously my application class that contain parse initializing is called twice even though I only setUp my activity once.

This my code

```
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);
    }
```

and one of my test methods

```
    @Test
    public void registerButtonLaunchSignUpActivity() throws Exception {
        // Arrange
        Class clazz = SignUpActivity.class;
        Intent expectedIntent = new Intent(activity,clazz);

        // Act
        activity.register_button.callOnClick();

        // Assert
        ShadowActivity shadowActivity = Shadows.shadowOf(activity);
        Intent actualIntent = shadowActivity.getNextStartedActivity();
        assertTrue(expectedIntent.filterEquals(actualIntent));
    }
```

The other test methods have a similar content.

**UPDATE**

My test class

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)
public class MainActivityRobolectricTest {

    MainActivity activity;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void registerButtonLaunchSignUpActivity() throws Exception {
        // Arrange
        Class clazz = SignUpActivity.class;
        Intent expectedIntent = new Intent(activity,clazz);

        // Act
        activity.register_button.callOnClick();

        // Assert
        ShadowActivity shadowActivity = Shadows.shadowOf(activity);
        Intent actualIntent = shadowActivity.getNextStartedActivity();
        assertTrue(expectedIntent.filterEquals(actualIntent));
    }

    @Test
    public void alreadyHaveAccountButtonLaunchLogInActivity() throws Exception {
        // Arrange
        Class clazz = LogIn.class;
        Intent expectedIntent = new Intent(activity,clazz);

        // Act
        activity.already_have_account_textView.callOnClick();

        // Assert
        ShadowActivity shadowActivity = Shadows.shadowOf(activity);
        Intent actualIntent = shadowActivity.getNextStartedActivity();
        assertTrue(expectedIntent.filterEquals(actualIntent));
    }
}
```

My application class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private Tracker mTracker;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
        ParseObject.registerSubclass(Question.class);
        ParseObject.registerSubclass(Response.class);
        ParseObject.registerSubclass(Activity.class);
        ParseObject.registerSubclass(Category.class);
        ParseObject.registerSubclass(User.class);
        Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(MyApplication.this)
                .applicationId(ParseConstants.PARSE_APP_ID)
                .server(ParseConstants.PARSE_SERVER_URL)
                .enableLocalDataStore()
                .build()
        );
        ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
        ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
        ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(getApplicationContext());
        //ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
        final ParseInstallation parseInstallation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
        parseInstallation.put("GCMSenderId","xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        parseInstallation.saveInBackground();
    }

    synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
        if (mTracker == null) {
            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            // To enable debug logging use: adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
            mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
        }
        return mTracker;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you "test a couples of methods together"? Do you run it in Android Studio?

Comment: Yes I right click above my class and choose run MyActivityTest

Comment: Do you have a custom runner or anything else that interfere with tests run? Nothing strange with your tests and similar ours run normal on our side?

Comment: Not actually, there is some initialisations inside my application class that's it, btw I'm using robolectric:3.2.1 .

Comment: We have similar setup and don't have issues with it. Can you share entire test? and maybe application class?

Comment: I think it is Parse keeping the instance of your app. If you disable it in app and run tests do you see same error? (They might fail but at least with expectable error)

Comment: I don't that will make sens, I've tested robolectric with methods that doesn't need initialising the app with parse and every thing work's fine, but those 2 methods I'm testing both call parse query, so if I disable parse they won't work anyway.

Comment: I would extract all parse login in the class and mock it in the test. However class that holds Parse logic is still untestable with Robolectric. So you should write the instrumental tests

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate you're effort.